# Android how to update value of next tab?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, sharedpreferences, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have 2 `Fragments` `FragmentA` and `FragmentB`. Using these two I have created a `FragmentActivity` to show 2 `fragments` in Tab format, Tab A and B. `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` and `ViewPager` have been used to create the Tab `view`. Tab A has a `EditText` and a `Button`. Tab B has a TextView only. User will input value in Tab A `EditText`, on `button` click first it will save the data in `SharedPreferences` and then it will go to Tab B and show the value of Tab A `EditText`. I have saved the data in `SharePrefereces` but still can't show the value in Tab B.

My Tab A:

```
confirmButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View view) {
session.setValue(mValue.getText().toString());
ViewPager mViewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pager);
mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                }
            });
```

My Tab B:

```
mValueFromTabA.setText(session.getValue());
```

Comment: as far as i know, the tabs onCreate() or orResume() is not called as and when the tab gets visible, coz they are prepared and before hand. So i would call an explicit method from FramgmentActivity which does the setting of text part mValueFromTabA.setText(session.getValue());, some thing like refreshTextValueOnTab2(); on button click event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take one string and add the Getters and setters into your `FragmentActivity` class.

Like...

```
String HistoryFragment;

public String getHistoryFragment() {
    return HistoryFragment;
}


public void setHistoryFragment(String historyFragment) {
    HistoryFragment = historyFragment;
}
```

Then after we can access another fragment from our current fragment by calling `findFragmentByTag(<tag of target fragment>)`.

For the more information check the link [Communication between Fragments in ViewPager](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2012/06/communication-between-fragments-in.html).

Answer (score 0):

This means that your fragments that are not visible to the user are still being kept in memory, so their onCreate methods won't be called when they're redisplayed. You can force them to be kicked out of memory when you switch pages by setting the ViewPager's offscreen page limit to 0.

```
mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0);
```

Comment: still the same. My 2nd tab onCreate is not being called. As a result my 2nd tab is not being updated with the value of 1st tab.

Comment: it will work, but it takes few seconds to refresh.check it properly.